# Please recommend a problem book with solutions on graduate level real analysis and measure theory

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, book-recommendation

I'd like to find a problem book (with solutions) about graduate level real analysis (measure theory). That is, at the level of the books by Royden or Zygmund.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Problems-Mathematical-Analysis-Student-Library/dp/0821832980         http://www.amazon.de/Problems-Real-Analysis-Charalambos-Aliprantis/dp/B009NNX2L4

Answer (score 2):

(1) Bogachev: Measure Theory Volumes I and II.

(2) Bruckner: Real analysis

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The only book I know that is like that is "Schaum Outline Series: Real variables", but I dont really know the quality of the excercises at all, every other 'Real analysis', problem book I know doesnt include measure theory.